# dnn could not load type

Tags: types, dotnetnuke

I have a site created with help of DotNetNuke.After I added new module to the project I click Build Solution and i get an error "could not load type XYZ".
My  module definition

```
       <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DemoRequestControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="ABC.Controls.DemoRequest.DemoRequestControl" %>
```

DemoRequestControl.ascx.cs file namespace

```
namespace ABC.Controls.DemoReport
{
    public partial class DemoReportControl : PortalModuleBase
```

Maybe some reference is missing or it's a namespaces problem... I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks good. I believe you are using a web application project for your module and didn't set the build path. do this:

- Project Properties > Build
- Choose your dnn portal's bin directory as output path.

This way your module's dll will be in /Bin folder and dnn can load the assembly.

Let me know if you need any other help.

Answer (score 0):

Another common cause for this error is an incompatible dll file. This occurs if you install/update a module. If the whole DNN site goes down and you get the dreaded DNN Error and part of the url looks like `/Default.aspx?tabid=56&error=Could+not+load+type+%27DotNetNuke....`, here's how you get the site back;

1. Go to [DNN Codeplex site](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/) and download the **Install** file of your current DNN Version. ***Very important*** to select the same version as your DNN site.
2. Unzip Folder and open the **bin** folder.
3. Copy the entire contents of the bin folder.
4. Open the bin folder in your website folder and paste into this folder replacing the old dll files.
5. Fire up your site again and you should be back in business.